# Invoke Method with client.soda ( Statement Object Model )

Tags: methods, esper, invocation, som

I am trying to build Esper EPL statements in Java.

I use the com.espertech.esper.client.soda lib for this, but I can't find
a tutorial to help me.

The PatternExpressions are the only part that I need as of now.

As an example let's use the EPL:

```
every a=Event((a).getEventTypeCode()='E00001')
```

So he should trigger on every Event with the event type code E00001, we get the code by
calling the getEventTypeCode Method.

How do I project this to SOM?

With:

```
PatternExpr pattern = Patterns.everyFilter("Event","a");
```

I only get:

```
every a=Event
```

(of course)

I know there is a class called "MethodInvocationStream" but I don't know how to use it.
And I cannot find examples for its use.

Thanks to user650839 I found out how to add Methods via SOM.
Here is a simple EPL as an SOM Object: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFfZv.jpg
[image: EPL as SOM Object]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One source of info is the javadoc.
You could simply do the reverse and compile EPL text to a model object and inspect that. Use "epAdmin.compileEPL", the output is the same object you want to build via API.\

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer!
I read through the javadoc before, but it couldn't help me.
However, your suggestion with the EPAdministrator class was very good.
It gave me the insight into the structure that I needed ( after I loaded it with the Expression ). It's hard to find proper examples and tutorials for esper even in the codehouse.
Thanks again!